# How to pick out specific entries in a field to create new output columns (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Wonder if you can help me out with this, this is my first post so please go easy on me :-)

I wanted to adapt this query to separate certain values that may appear in the 'service code' field and put them into a separate column when output.

I've tweaked a report template which allows me to output the data easily.

The codes used follow the format of _IHPNR001A, the last two numbers differentiate the intended column. So

- 1-15 would be **Type of Visit**,
- 16-69 would be **Services 1** and **Services 2** if there's a second occurrence,
- 70-99 would be **Rec Program**.

All the other fields of data I'm pulling (ie DOB) also need to still be present, but I wanted to condense the data based on the 'ID' field.

Its as follows...

```
SELECT b.id as 'ID', bd.service_code as 'Service Code', bs.description as 'Service Desc', b.demographic_no as 'Demo No', b.demographic_name as 'Demo Name', b.provider_no as 'Provider No', b.dob as 'DOB', demo.sex as 'Gender', b.appointment_no as 'Appt No',   bd.dx as 'diag. Code', b.billing_date as 'Billing Date'

FROM billing_on_cheader1 b, billing_on_item bd, billingservice bs, demographic demo

WHERE b.provider_no = {provider_no} and b.id = bd.ch1_id 
   and b.status <> 'D' 
   and b.billing_date >='{billing_date_start}' and b.billing_date     <='{billing_date_end}' 
   and bs.service_code = bd.service_code
   and b.demographic_no = demo.demographic_no;

    </query>
  <param id="provider_no" type="list" description="Provider Number">
  <param-query>select provider_no, CONCAT(last_name, ', ', first_name, '     (', provider_no, ')') from provider order by last_name;</param-query>
   </param>
   <param id="billing_date_start" type="date" description="Billing date start">
   </param>
   <param id="billing_date_end" type="date" description="Billing date end">
   </param>
    </report>
```

The current results are:

[image]

My expected results are:

[image]

My attempt at applying suggestion:

```
<report title="IHP STATS COLLECTION v13" description="IHP Stats Test -(Version 13)" active="1">
```

```
SELECT
b.demographic_no as 'Demo No', b.demographic_name as 'Demo Name', b.dob as 'DOB', demo.sex as 'Gender', b.provider_no as 'Provider No', bd.dx as 'diag. Code', b.billing_date as 'Billing Date',
bdtv.ch1_id as 'ID', bdtv.service_code as 'Type of Visit',
bds1.service_code as 'Services 1',
bds2.service_code as 'Services 2',
bdrp.service_code as 'Rec Program'
FROM billing_on_item bdtv, billing_on_cheader1 b, billing_on_item bd, billingservice bs, demographic demo
LEFT JOIN billing_on_item bds1 
 ON bds1.ch1_id = bdtv.ch1_id 
 AND SUBSTRING(bds1.service_code, -3, 2) BETWEEN 16 AND 69
LEFT JOIN billing_on_item bds2 
 ON bds2.ch1_id = bdtv.ch1_id 
 AND SUBSTRING(bds2.service_code, -3, 2) BETWEEN 16 AND 69
 AND bds2.service_code <> bds1.service_code 
LEFT JOIN billing_on_item bdrp 
 ON bdrp.ch1_id = bdtv.ch1_id AND SUBSTRING(bdrp.service_code, -3, 2) BETWEEN 70 AND 99
WHERE SUBSTRING(bdtv.service_code, -3, 2) BETWEEN 0 AND 15
AND b.provider_no = {provider_no} and b.id = bd.ch1_id 
   and b.status <> 'D' 
   and b.billing_date >='{billing_date_start}' and b.billing_date <='{billing_date_end}' 
   and bs.service_code = bd.service_code
and b.demographic_no = demo.demographic_no;
GROUP BY bdtv.ch1_id;

</query>
  <param id="provider_no" type="list" description="Provider Number">
  <param-query> select provider_no, CONCAT(last_name, ', ', first_name, ' (', provider_no, ')') from provider order by last_name;</param-query>
   </param>
   <param id="billing_date_start" type="date" description="Billing date start">
   </param>
   <param id="billing_date_end" type="date" description="Billing date end">
   </param>
</report>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to transpose the table - e.g. turn rows into columns based on some row criteria.

You could achieve that by self joining the `billing_on_item` table multiple times. Something along the lines of

```
SELECT 
bdtv.ch1_id as 'ID', bdtv.service_code as 'Type of Visit',
bds1.service_code as 'Services 1',
bds2.service_code as 'Services 2',
bdrp.service_code as 'Rec Program'
FROM billing_on_item bdtv
LEFT JOIN billing_on_item bds1 
     ON bds1.ch1_id = bdtv.ch1_id 
     AND SUBSTRING(bds1.service_code, -3, 2) BETWEEN 16 AND 69
LEFT JOIN billing_on_item bds2 
     ON bds2.ch1_id = bdtv.ch1_id 
     AND SUBSTRING(bds2.service_code, -3, 2) BETWEEN 16 AND 69
     AND bds2.service_code <> bds1.service_code 
LEFT JOIN billing_on_item bdrp 
     ON bdrp.ch1_id = bdtv.ch1_id AND SUBSTRING(bdrp.service_code, -3, 2) BETWEEN 70 AND 99
WHERE SUBSTRING(bdtv.service_code, -3, 2) BETWEEN 0 AND 15
GROUP BY bdtv.ch1_id
```

as presented here: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a5a3/1/0)

Updated answer with all the tables involved:

```
SELECT b.demographic_name as 'Demo Name', b.dob as 'DOB', 
demo.sex as 'Gender', 
b.provider_no as 'Provider No', bdtv.dx as 'diag. Code', 
b.billing_date as 'Billing Date',
bdtv.ch1_id as 'ID', bdtv.service_code as 'Type of Visit',
bds1.service_code as 'Services 1',
bds2.service_code as 'Services 2',
bdrp.service_code as 'Rec Program'
FROM billing_on_cheader1 b
JOIN demographic demo ON b.demographic_no = demo.demographic_no
JOIN billing_on_item bdtv ON b.id = bdtv.ch1_id
LEFT JOIN billing_on_item bds1 
 ON bds1.ch1_id = bdtv.ch1_id 
 AND SUBSTRING(bds1.service_code, -3, 2) BETWEEN 16 AND 69
LEFT JOIN billing_on_item bds2 
 ON bds2.ch1_id = bdtv.ch1_id 
 AND SUBSTRING(bds2.service_code, -3, 2) BETWEEN 16 AND 69
 AND bds2.service_code <> bds1.service_code 
LEFT JOIN billing_on_item bdrp 
 ON bdrp.ch1_id = bdtv.ch1_id AND SUBSTRING(bdrp.service_code, -3, 2) BETWEEN 70 AND 99
WHERE SUBSTRING(bdtv.service_code, -3, 2) BETWEEN 0 AND 15
AND b.provider_no = 54 AND b.status <> 'D'
GROUP BY bdtv.ch1_id;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54805/4)

Comment: Thanks  for looking at my issue, your solution looks great in the link you provided, exactly as I intended. However I can't fully test it until I place it in the existing report template. I tried doing this but I get 'SQL Error', I don't think I've written it out correctly. I tried...

Comment: (See above - I've added it to my question)

Comment: Updated the answer to involve all the tables from your original query. I don't have any data so It could be wrong still. Would you fill a SQLFiddle with a test data in all the tables?

Comment: The query didn't seem to work so I tried to add the data in SQL Fiddle but it wouldn't accept my attempt, sorry! please see my adjusted question, I've included the data there. Not sure if I need to add additional fields in the tables, I've just entered the data used (Thanks for your patience) :-)

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Hope this is what you wanted to get.

Comment: After making a couple of tweaks, works perfectly :-)

Comment: Really appreciate the time you spent on my problem Te Ko! Thanks for expanding my knowledge & introducing me to new tools/methods too